# Set grid cell background transparency

Tags: wxpython

How can I set the background transparency of a grid cell. Or is it impossible?

```
import wx
import wx.grid


class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        grid = wx.grid.Grid(self)
        grid.CreateGrid(3, 3)

        grid.SetCellBackgroundColour(0, 0, wx.Colour(255, 0, 0, 0))
        grid.SetCellBackgroundColour(1, 0, wx.Colour(255, 0, 0, 127))
        grid.SetCellBackgroundColour(2, 0, wx.Colour(255, 0, 0, 255))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

WxPython 4.0.7.post2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import wx
import wx.grid


def getRGBA(rgb, alpha):
    """Create RGBA.

    Y = 255 - P * (255 - X), X - RGB item, P - aplha (0...1)

    :param tuple rgb:
    :param float alpha:
    :return: New RGB
    :rtype: tuple
    """
    return tuple(round(255 - alpha * (255 - v)) for v in rgb)


class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        grid = wx.grid.Grid(self)
        grid.CreateGrid(3, 3)

        grid.SetCellBackgroundColour(0, 0, wx.Colour(255, 0, 0, 0))
        grid.SetCellBackgroundColour(1, 0, wx.Colour((255, 0, 0, 127)))
        grid.SetCellBackgroundColour(2, 0, wx.Colour(255, 0, 0, 255))

        grid.SetCellBackgroundColour(0, 1, wx.Colour(getRGBA((255, 0, 0), 1)))
        grid.SetCellBackgroundColour(1, 1, wx.Colour(getRGBA((255, 0, 0), 0.5)))
        grid.SetCellBackgroundColour(2, 1, wx.Colour(getRGBA((255, 0, 0), 0)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]